# How do you multiple left join the same table from 2 different tables in the same query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I am in the process of refactoring some old SQL Server stored procs that are utilizing the *= operator instead of the preferred ANSI LEFT JOIN syntax.  One of the procs I'm working on is giving me trouble because it's trying to left join the same table from 2 different tables in the same FROM clause and it's not returning the same results as the original old procedure returned.

I've refactored about 20 other stored procs that I have but none of them do multiple left joins like this on the same table.  The old *= operator seems to have simplified this one.  As you can see it was pretty straightforward to join on table3 all in the same where clause.

## OLD CODE

SELECT ...
TABLE3.column10

FROM    TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3
WHERE TABLE1.column5 *= TABLE3.column5
and     TABLE2.column8 *= TABLE3.column8

## NEW CODE

SELECT
TABLE3.colum10 
FROM
TABLE1
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 T3a
ON TABLE1.column5 = T3a.column5,

TABLE2
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 T3b
ON TABLE2.column8 = T3b.column8

Now since I have to alias TABLE3 in the new from clause, I don't get the expected results in my select of column10.

I'm hoping by looking at the old and new query you can kinda see what I'm shooting for.  I can provide more detail if necessary but I am trying to keep my question as simple as possible at first.

Comment: Refer to the table in your `SELECT` by its alias. Also, you should really be using ANSI-92 JOIN syntax all the time; not just when you can't use the ANSI-89 LEFT JOIN syntax anymore. The old syntax was replaced 27 years ago for good reason. :) I assume you aren't after a `CROSS JOIN` to `TABLE2` in your second query? That's what you currently have. If that is your intention change to using a `CROSS JOIN`, if not then use a proper `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: A difficulty in answering your question is that there is scant documentation or examples for how 3+-table old-style joins were guaranteed to work, or seen to work, or gave buggy answers contrary to documentation, or were translated correctly or buggily by SQL Server migration tools. So it would help a lot if you gave some example actual output(s) and a description of what translation you "expect" here. Anyway: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); clear specification & explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why aren't you doing this?

```
SELECT t3.colum10 
FROM TABLE1 t1 CROSS JOIN
     TABLE2 t2 LEFT JOIN
     TABLE3 T3
     ON t1.column5 = T3a.column5 AND
        t2.column8 = T3b.column8;
```

Actually, I get a little confused with the old syntax, but I think you want:

```
SELECT t3.colum10 
FROM TABLE3 t3 LEFT JOIN
     TABLE1 t1
     ON t1.column5 = T3.column5 LEFT JOIN
     TABLE2 t2
     ON t2.column8 = T3.column8;
```

Or at least this logic makes more sense to me, regarding the three tables.  However, the joins are pretty superfluous here.

Comment: Must admit, this seems like an odd query (not saying the answer here is wrong). Considering that the query has a `LEFT JOIN` to `TABLE3` then this is going to return rows with the value `NULL` and show no other columns from the other tables; making the row have little to no meaning.

Comment: @Larnu . . . I think the second query is the correct one.  I think the `*=` means to keep all rows on the *other* side, so it really wants `table3` to be first.

Comment: You might be right. It's still a confused query though, as if the latter is correct then why perform a `LEFT JOIN` at all apart from to create duplicate rows? Perhaps the OP has overly simplified the query; but if so that may mean we're way off base here. :/

Comment: `*=` for the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` second query is the closest one, and yes, the old syntax of SQL Server always makes things creeper. Thank god they changed it to ANSI.

Comment: CROSS JOIN saved the day!  Didn't even think of it, not my strong suit obviously lol...   Thank you for saving my week!